# netbeans Swing String.valueOf() conversion issue

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

When I try to execute `String y = String.valueOf(int x)` inside an action listener my GUI freezes up.  Specifically when passing from another class of the same package to the GUI, regardless of when the conversion takes place.  Anyone know why?

```
String add(String a, String b) {
  int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
  int y = Integer.parseInt(b);
  int c = x + y;
  String temp = String.valueOf(c);
  return temp;
}

private void NextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  String tempx = stringAR[n];
  String tempy = stringAR[t];

  String out = add(tempx, tempy);
}
```

This causes my GUI to freeze but only if the Strings come from the global array `stringAR`.

Comment: We would need to see code. Consider an SSCCE. I doubt its String.valueOf() doing it to you.

Comment: Recommend posting your code so we can further assist you

Comment: I have never seen the object or type `Int`.

Comment: It's a Java naming conversion to begin method names with lowercase. Uppercases are for classes.

Answer (score 0):

No one has answered except in comments, because it may be impossible to give an answer with as little info as you've provided, but I'll try. (yes, please provide an SSCCE, like someone has suggested).

> This causes my GUI to freeze but only if the Strings come from the global array stringAR.

Are you sure your StringAR is not null, and that its length is >= 2?

All GUI events are processed in the single thread. Therefore, one reason GUI might freeze would be an infinite (or just very long) loop in the event thread. Another (and that would  only likely freeze a part of the GUI, not the entire thing) would be an uncaught exception. Hence I am suspecting a NullPointerException or similar.

Personally, I don't know how developers live without a debugger. I swear by Eclipse, but I've heard NetBeans has become pretty great, too. Why not step through your code in debugger? Or, if you are a hard-core Unix type, debug by peppering your code print statements, log files, etc. Unit testing, too.

Last but not least, never swallow exceptions silently unless you know exactly what you are doing. Handle your exceptions explicitly.